# Need help in integration with five9 with salesforce

Tags: managed-package, integration

I have searched a lot...but never got full configuration information from anywhere.
if someone knows then please let me know..

if any reference link or anything about it

Answer (score 0):

I have tried their free trial before.  After installing their dialer, we had someone from Five9 to guide us through the process (via emails and screen share).  If you're behind a firewall, you would also need to open the required ports.

I don't think there's any detailed documents publicly available on configuration setup.   It varies case by case depending on your environemnt and desired connection method (e.g. softphone vs PSTN) so the easiest way is to get in touch with them.